# Defining variable in a class

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, and I'm getting undefined variable `$firstDect` even though it is defined:

```
class Deck
{
    public function getdeck()
    {
        $firstDeck = new Deck();
        return $this->firstDeck;
    }
}
```

and,

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php foreach ($firstDeck->getDeck() as $card): ?>
        <img class="col-md-3" src="<?php echo $card->getImage(); ?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are creating the object within itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should start by reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

```
class Deck
{
   /* You have to define variable something like below before 
      accessing $this->firstDeck 
   */
   public $firstDeck;


   public function getdeck()
   {
       $this->firstDeck = new Deck();
       return $this->firstDeck;
   }
}
```

Read More from [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use following class:

```
class Deck
    {
        public $firstDeck;
        public function getdeck()
        {
            $this->firstDeck = new Deck();
            return $this->firstDeck;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the variable in function itself.

```
 public function getdeck()
        {
            $firstDeck = new Deck();
            return $this->firstDeck;
        }
```

You can't use `$this` with variables declared inside functions, `$this` is used to reference variable declared at class level. You can rewrite your function like this,

```
 public function getdeck()
        {
            $firstDeck = new Deck();
            return $firstDeck;
        }
```

or

You can define the variable at class level like this,

```
class Deck
    {
        private $firstDeck;
        public function getdeck()
        {
            $this->firstDeck = new Deck();
            return $this->firstDeck;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reserved word `$this` is a reference to the object of the class you are currently in. So `$this->firstDeck` indicates that you have a class member with the name `$firstDeck`, which you do not have.

You either declare it in your class as a member

```
class Deck
{
    private $firstDeck;
    public getdeck() { ... }
}
```

or you just write

```
public getdeck() 
{
    $firstdeck = new Deck();
    return $firstdeck;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an error, use this :

```
    public function getdeck()
    {
        $firstDeck = new Deck();
        return $firstDeck ->firstDeck;
    }
```

$this relate to the self class.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of things are wrong.

You are trying to use a variable defined inside a function.

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
class Deck{
    public function getDeck(){
        return array(card1, card2...);
    }
}

$firstDeck = new Deck();
```

This leaves some undefined questions about what a card is or other stuff which is out of scope on the question.

On the other side, i used an array to assure that the output of the `getDeck` method is iterable, but i think there are ways to make your class iterable by itself, you just have to look up in the documentation.

Comment: Feedback to go with downvote are always appreciated.